# Evolutionary factors that might create Grey Aliens?

Tags: evolution, aliens

I know everyone knows about the typical "grey alien" I was just wondering if a species like them really existed what type of environment would they live in? And what certain factors in their environment would lead to their existence?

I also know the depiction of the Greys varies from very short 3-4 ft and very tall 6 ft + tall. Let's just assume they are short 3-4 ft instead.

Comment: What is a typical "grey alien"?

Comment: A picture of what i'm referring to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_alien#/media/File%3AAlienigena.jpg

Answer (score 4):

With their enlarged heads (which implies larger brains), thinner arms and legs (implying a more mental, less physical, work load), their pale skin tones and large eyes (from controlled exposure to sunlight), the Greys could easily share our evolutionary history and count us as their uncivilized forebears.

The Greys are what we will look like once evolution has had enough time to adapt us completely to the artificial environment which we call civilization.

Comment: Humans born and evolved for life in zero gravity for generations.  Bones elongated and thinned without the constant pull of gravity.   Black eyes adapted to the constant unvarying mechanical light.

Comment: Atlantean forebears sent an ark on a long journey to safe guard mankind's legacy.  Only, the cataclysm that destroyed their civilisation left behind a small pocket of humanity in northern Africa.

Comment: @Lumberjack.  These are excellent ideas!  You should make them into an answer.  I've always perferred the "Aliens are from our future" trop because it doesn't require an entirely seperate life-bearing planet and evolutionary tree.  Your Atlantean angle allows the Aliens to come from our past, which has all of the same attributes of my answer, plus some really cool spin-off ramifications.  Post it as an answer!